# Set Powershell Predictive Intellisense Off by default

Tags: powershell, windows-11, powershell-7.0

I'm using Powershell 7.3.3 in Windows 11 and the Predictive Intellisense feature is on by default unless I turn it off manually each time I use it. Is there any way to turn it off (or back on) permanently without setting it each time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn the intellisense feature off.

[Intellisense](https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/daily-powershell/powershell-predictive-intellisense/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20enable%20the%20predictive,the%20option%20cmdlet%20for%20PSReadline.&text=To%20disable%20the%20feature%2C%20set%20the%20source%20back%20to%20none.)

.

**Enable Predictive IntelliSense:**

You can enable the predictive IntelliSense feature with the option cmdlet for PSReadline.

Set-PSReadlineOption -PredictionSource History

**To disable the feature, set the source back to none.**

Set-PSReadlineOption -PredictionSource None

[Start Powershell as Admin before setting. The above is for Powershell 7.  Powershell 6 appears to be quite different in settings.]

Comment: And you can get the current value, with this ps command: get-psreadlineoption | %{echo $_.PredictionSource}